# How to convert a dictionary value from a string to an int (Or how do I better write my code read it the value as an integer) in python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am attempting to open a text file the following way:
[image]

However, the value is reading as a string as opposed to an int. How do I get the value from the text file to read as an int? For example a file reading CSCI 160:4  CSCI 289:3  EE 201:4    MATH 208:3 prints out as the dictionary {'CSCI 160': '4', 'CSCI 289': '3', 'EE 201': '4', 'MATH 208': '3'}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you create `ClassDict` you can convert all values to integers, for example:

```py
ClassDict = {k: int(v) for k, v in ClassDict.items()}
print(ClassDict)
```

Prints:

```py
{'CSCI 160': 4, 'CSCI 289': 3, 'EE 201': 4, 'MATH 208': 3}
```